# Sum of all mex of subarrays of an array

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find sum of mex of subarrays of an array but i have problem in optimizing it. I want to work faster than it happen in my code. please help me.
Mex : the smallest natural number that not present in a set.
It's my code

```
from itertools import count, filterfalse 
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int,input().split()))
mex = 0
x = sorted(x)
r = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        q = x[i:j+1]
        mex += int(next(filterfalse(set(q).__contains__, count(1))))
print(mex)
```

Comment: Why do you think it can run faster?

Comment: It's work slow for more count such as 100000 and O(n*(n+1)/2) is slow.

Comment: Solution is available online. https://codedrills.io/problems/subarray-mex-sum